# How would i extract bits in crystal

Tags: hex, virtual-machine, extract, crystal-lang

How would i extract bits of a hex number in crystal lang which is mostly like ruby because i am able to extract a byte but i cannot extract 4 bits of one cause that is what i need to do here is what I want to extract. 
0x0312FCFC
------^^(the 1 and 2)
How would i extract those 2
here is my code to extract the first one and the last 4

```
op = ((x.to_i(16)) >> 24) & 0xff
im = (x.to_i(16)) & 0xffff
```

What i have tried was

```
a1 = ((x.to_i(16)) >> 16) & 0xf0
a2 = ((x.to_i(16)) >> 16) & 0x0f
```

Answer (score 2):

First, shift the number of bits that you need to the right. In your example, it should be 16 (`4*4`, as you want to skip the last 4 hex chars `FCFC`) and 20 (`5*4`, skipping `2FCFC`). Then mask the last byte (`... & 0xF`).

```
x = 0x0312FCFC
a = (x >> 16) & 0xF   # a = 2
b = (x >> 20) & 0xF   # b = 1
```

And yes, the code is identical in Ruby and Crystal.